# orthogonal matrix and elementary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Answer is False. But I can't think of the counter example... Could anybody have it?

Let A be an orthogonal 4 x 4 matrix such that $$ Ae_1 = e_2, Ae_2 = e_3, Ae_3 = e_1$$ Then $$Ae_4 = e_4 $$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Then $Ae_4 = -e_4$.

Comment: @martini Good enough for an answer, innit?

Comment: $e_4$ has to be an eigenvector of $A$, and it has to have an eigenvalue of $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Then $Ae_4 = -e_4$.

On the other side, the given three conditions and orthogonality of $A$ imply $Ae_4 \in \{\pm e_4\}$, as $Ae_4 \cdot Ae_i = e_4 \cdot e_i = 0$ for $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ hence $Ae_4 \cdot e_j = 0$ for $j \in \{1,2,3\}$. So $Ae_4 = \alpha e_4$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. Now $1 = Ae_4 \cdot Ae_4 = \alpha^2$ gives $\alpha \in\{\pm 1\}$.